# command not found: flow

Tags: command, zsh

I followed the Flow [installation](https://flow.org/en/docs/install/) guide for `npm` & `babel` and when I get to the second stage where you `flow init` I keep getting the error message `zsh command not found: flow`. I installed flow into my project (a branch of my Gatsby blog) for testing/debugging purposes. It is not installed globally, which is what the Flow docs state is the best practice:

> Flow works best when installed per-project with explicit versioning rather than globally.

I have been having a similar issue with [Lume](https://lumeland.github.io/) that returns `zsh command not found: lume`

If I enter `echo $PATH`

The colon delimited list should have user/local/.deno/bin:$PATH but it is not there. If I add it by running:

`export PATH="/Users/yourUserName/.deno/bin:$PATH"`

Than I am able to run `lume commands`. However, when I try to run `lume commands` the next day I have to go through the whole process once more as the error crops up again...

My question here today is regarding the `Flow` error and getting it sorted. I only mention the `Lume` error because it makes me fairly certain something is messed up in $Path or my Zsh config. I am just not sure what. The only caveat to that hunch though is that Deno is a global install, whereas Flow is installed directly into my project...
So, maybe the two errors while the same syntax are totally separate?

Thank you in advance for any guidance/suggestions. Cheers!

Comment: Read the zsh-man-page, in particular the section called _INVOCATION_. It describes which files zsh is processing on each startup, and it is in a suitable one of those files where you put the commands which should be executed automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across [this](https://youtu.be/0HlqX4lQZas) video from 2017 no less and the host had issues with `flow` not working within the project and so he installed it globally. I gave it a shot and the flow error `zsh command not found: flow` has been resolved...